# Enable access to AWS security group from Google Cloud project

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I host my database with AWS on an RDS MySQL instance.

I would like to give all instances I create in a specific Google Cloud project to be whitelisted for the RDS security group.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you know the IP addresses of your GCP clients then you could use those. Or route the clients through NAT and use its IP. Or maybe create a VPN between the GCP project VPC and the AWS VPC. Just some ideas to look into.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give NAT a go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only couple of instances, you can grant them public, static IPs - ([1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static)).  It can be new IPs or you can promote those they already have.
If you have or expect many instances to interact with AWS, you should consider NAT  ([2](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/set-up-network-address-translation)) or VPN Interconnect ([3](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/build-ha-vpn-connections-google-cloud-aws)) as suggested by @jarmod.
There are also Dedicated Interconnect ([4](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/concepts/dedicated-overview)) and Partner Interconnect ([5](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/concepts/partner-overview)) options.

Remember to check the estimated cost in [Pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) before commiting to any of the options.